# How do I render 1 of 3 SVGs inside a component using conditions in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Here is the code that I have now. I can't figure this out. Trying to render an SVG icon based on the prop. For example  would render a house icon

```
import React from "react";


    function BuildingIcon() {
      return <img src="./building.svg" alt="building" />;
    }

    function HouseIcon() {
      return <img src="./house.svg" alt="house" />;
    }

    function LatlongIcon() {
      return <img src="./latlong.svg" alt="globe" />;
    }
    function Icon(props) {
      const iconStyle = props.iconStyle;
      switch (iconStyle) {
        case "building":
          return <BuildingIcon />;
        case "house":
          return <HouseIcon />;
        case "latlong":
          return <LatlongIcon />;
        default:
          return <HouseIcon />;
      }
    }

    export default Icon;
```

Comment: Are you certain that the iconStyle prop is being handed down to the Icon() function?

Answer (score 0):

You could actually just import the images into your component, and them specifying them as the `src` value.

```
import logo from "./lat-long.png";
```

In addition, there is no need to go 2 levels deep when you destructure them.

In addition, you should check if `iconStyle` is properly passed down to your component, and that `props.iconStyle` is defined.

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./lat-long.png";

function BuildingIcon() {
  return <img src={logo} alt="globe" />;
}

function HouseIcon() {
  return <img width="24px" src={logo}  alt="globe" />;
}

function LatlongIcon() {
  return <img src={logo}  alt="globe" />;
}

function Icon(props) {
  const { iconStyle } = props;
  switch (iconStyle) {
    case "building":
      return <BuildingIcon />;
    case "house":
      return <HouseIcon />;
    case "latlong":
      return <LatlongIcon />;
    default:
      return <HouseIcon />;
  }
}
```

Comment: here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/components-p482p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @JoshCusick i have updated my answer. In addition, I have made changes to the demo to fix the issue https://codesandbox.io/s/components-pl40h